# Promise call in afterAll not executed

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm testing a web application that uses cloudant. I set up a test db in the beforeAll() and want to delete it after all tests in the afterAll().

The code in before gets executed and I get the db created, but for some reason the code in the after is not being executed. To be more precise, the call to cloudant api is not executed. In both before and after uses the same API that is handled promise.

In my test.js

```
const cloudant = require('../storage/cloudant');

const dbname = 'testdb';
const doc = { _id: 'testDocument' };
const dbConfig = { dbname, doc };

beforeAll(() => {
  cloudant.createDB(dbname)
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .then(() => cloudant.createDocument(dbConfig));
});

afterAll(() => {
  console.log('It is called');
  cloudant.deleteDatabase(dbname).then((res) => console.log(res)).catch(e => console.log(e));

// test templates functions
test('Read documnet from cloudant', async () => {
  const response = await cloudant.readDocument(dbname, doc._id);
  expect(response._id).toBe(doc._id);
});
```

I would expect the db to be deleted after the test execution. However the only thing that seams to be called in the afterALL is the console.log; 
I get no exception or error for the deleteDatabase call.
The deleteDatabase method works. I tested it in a separate js script.

```
cloudant.deleteDatabase(dbname)
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

returns `{ ok: true }`

The delete method is defined as follow:

```
 async deleteDatabase(dbname) {
    return this.cloudantDB.db.destroy(dbname);
  }
```

The test results are as follow:

```
> jest server/test

[2019-08-08T10:58:55.132] [INFO] App-cloudant - creating new db: testdb
[2019-08-08T10:58:55.138] [INFO] App-cloudant - Reading testDocument
  console.log server/storage/cloudant.js:43
    testdb

  console.log server/storage/cloudant.js:44
    testDocument

  console.log server/test/test.js:17
    { ok: true }

[2019-08-08T10:58:55.487] [INFO] App-cloudant - Creating document [object Object]
 PASS  server/test/test.js
  ✓ adds 1 + 2 to equal 3 (2ms)
  ✓ Read documnet from cloudant (515ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.184s
Ran all test suites matching /server\/test/i.
  console.log server/test/test.js:22
    It is called
```

So the beforeAll works, the test executes successfully and the console.log from afterAll is called but not the deleteDatabase function.

Comment: You probably need to return that promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```js
afterAll(async () => {
  await Promise.resolve().then(console.log);
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works when it's called this way with async. But why is this working in beforeAll without async but not in afterAll ?

Comment: It really doesn’t, async tasks must always be awaited

Comment: I just tested @sp00m suggestion and return the promise instead, and it works as well, ` afterAll(() => cloudant.deleteDatabase(dbname).then(console.log('deleted')));`

Comment: Returning a promise is the same as using async, in fact async wraps your function in a promise